# css looking different in firefox

Tags: css

I have been working all night and yesterday on this header section in css, the link is below of how far I am so far but I am having trouble, can any css experts (or anyone) help?

http://friendproject.isgreat.org/header/
Looks exactly how I want it in google chrome, possible in IE beause it is similar to chrome

**Problem 1)**
My problem is in Firefox, when I mouseover a link, it changes the size on mouseover and mouse off like not the size, but makes the text move a little bit which doesn't look right and in chrome it does not do this.

**Problem 2)**
In firefox, when I mouseover a dropdown list, the list is not the correct width, in the CSS file I set the width for each dropdown list, this works in chrome but doesnt seem to work correctly in firefox for me

**UPDATE:**

I extracted this code from my site and posted it online just for this demo, I just checked the demo and realized that it is the same so my sites other CSS must be what is causing the issue that I see on my local site

**2nd UPDATE:**
It wasn't my css at all, I guess my browser font size was different, weird though firefox must remeber the font size you set on a site to site basis

Comment: What version of FF are you using?  I am seeing what looks like the exact same behavior in Chrome and FF 3.5.

Comment: I agree with Phairoh, in IE7 and FF 3.5 looks almost the same, only diffrence I spotted is lack of rounded corners support in IE.

Comment: What do you mean, when saying: "Looks exactly how I want it in google chrome, possible in IE beause it is similar to chrome"? IE is different to Firefox, Chrome and even to his own predecessors!

Comment: @Phairoh my firefox is 3.5.2, do the links appear to move in all your browsers or the opposite?

Comment: @Tim Büthe when I say that mean that 90% of the CSS work I do looks and acts the same in chrome and IE and firefox is usually the one that makes it look different so I would say IE and chrome are more similar to each other, in my experiences anyway

Comment: Normally I would ask for code, but in this case: do you have any screenshots that show the page as you want it, and how it differs in other browsers?

Comment: I did specifically mention browser font size. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you changed the default font size on either Chrome or Firefox? Because I see no difference between those two things on FF3.5 and Chrome 2. What versions are you using?

Comment: I just realized that, sorry, on my local site it acts different, I just realized this demo does not do it so I guess my sites other CSS must be interfering